# Master page in HTML5

Tags: android, html, cordova, master-pages

I am building a huge business application in android using phonegap. All I want to do is create a master page like concept of .net where all my scripts tag,header and footer will be placed to avoid rewriting of same code multiple times.

I'll use this .HTML file on every page. I tried following stuff but it didnt worked.

### Main HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/MyPersonnelTheme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/CustomJS/Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/CustomJS/AdditionalNotes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <div class="content-area">
    <form action="" method="post" id="abc" name="abc">

    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" width="100%">
        <li data-role="fieldcontain"  width="100%">
                <object name="foo" type="text/html" data="Memo.html"></object>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">



        <div data-role="header" data-theme="c">

        <h1>Additional Notes</h1>

        </div>
    <table align="center">
        <tr align="center">
            <td align="center">
                <div id="contentProgress" style="display: none" border="1">
                    <div align="center">
                        <h4>
                            Synchronization in progress...</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div align="center">
                        <img id="spin" src="Images/wait.gif" /></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="Reply">
                Additional Notes</label>
            <textarea cols="100" id="Reply" name="Reply" rows="20"></textarea>
        </li>

        <li data-role="fieldcontain">
            <table width="25%">
               <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="SAVE" data-mini="true" />
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            RetrieveFromDB();
            CheckSessionTimeout();
        });

        $('#submit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            savedata();
        });

    </script>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

Memo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/MyPersonnelTheme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/CustomJS/Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/CustomJS/AdditionalNotes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        CheckOnlineOfflineStatus();
        SetImageOnlineOffline('#onlineOffline');
        document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);
        document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
    }

    function onOnline() {
        SetOnlineOfflineImageFromCSS("true");
    }

    function onOffline() { 
        SetOnlineOfflineImageFromCSS("false");
    }  
</script>
</head>


    <div class="header-custom">
        <a href="javascript:goToNextPage('index.html')"><span class="home-icon"></span></a>
        <a href="javascript:goToNextPage('index.html')"><span class="wrds-logo"></span></a>
        <a href="javascript:javascript:SetLogOut()"><span id="onlineOffline" class="user-icon-online"></span></a>
    </div>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<head id="head">
 // you should import the Jquery.js
</head>
<script>
$(function(){
        var numItems = $('.include').length();
        if(numItems ==0 )
        $('#head').append('<script type="text/javascript" class="include" src="Include.js"></script>');
});
</script>
```

in Include.js you should have something like this:

```
    $(function(){
             $('#head').append('<script src="scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>');
             $('#head').append('<script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>');
             $('#head').append('<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>');
             $('#head').append('<script src="scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
             $('#head').append('<script src="scripts/CustomJS/Common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
             $('#head').append('<script src="scripts/CustomJS/AdditionalNotes.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
  });
```